# MEQP tools run comments Issues

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, composer, marketplace, meqp2

Im trying to run MEQP in magento 1.9.x version , but whenever I run
`php vendor/bin/phpcs D:\xampp\htdocs\projectname --standard=MEQP1` from the command line I get this output:

`dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d"; cd "../phpunit/phpunit" && pwd)`

`# See if we are running in Cygwin by checking for cygpath program
if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then`
       `# Cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
        # so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
        # we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
        # test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin
        if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
                dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");`
      `fi`
`fi`

`dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
"${dir}/phpunit" "$@"`

Please check the issues , let me know ur helpful comments .

Answer (score 1):

The script cannot run in the Windows console. With Cygwin however it should work: https://cygwin.com

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this Try below solution

Install `Cygwin` console and then run below command from `magento-coding-standard` folder which is located in your project root and run below command.

```
vendor/bin/phpcs F:/xampp/htdocs/demo/magento2/app/code/vendor name/extension name --standard=MEQP2 --severity=10 --extensions=php,phtml
```

That's it..!